# ASP.NET Core dll's in Debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am learning ASP.NET Core. I often trace code execution and inspect various files that were compiled in Release mode.

The problem with dll files compiled in Release mode is that you cannot use a Debugger to inspect fields and properties.

How do you inspect ASP.NET Core files that were compiled in Release mode? By that I mean everything in `Microsoft.AspNetCore` namespace (or even just `Microsoft` namespace).  [ASP.NET Core is open source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore), but I am not sure how to compile everything at once and use it.

Even better solution would be to use the original source files instead of compiled ones. That way, I can use `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/debugging-asp-net-core-2-source

Comment: I think you are looking for logger. You can change the mode to info, debug, error and write the values in file. you can change the log level if required and get more information using these file. [More details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 3):

Jetbrains got a piece of software that's called dotPeek. With it and JetBrains' decompiler, you should be able to debug through code in release mode, because of dotPeek's ability to generate symbol files.

After getting your hands on these symbol files, go into debug mode, then **Debug > Windows > Modules** Now you have to load in the symbol files, after that you should be able to step into the requested namespace.

ps. Remember to check the ***Enable .NET Framework source stepping*** checkbox under **Debug > Options > Debugging > General**